# Find kth number in sum array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array A with N elements I need to find pair (i,j) such that i is not equal to j and if we write the sum A[i]+A[j] for all pairs of (i,j) then it comes at the kth position.

**Example** : Let N=4 and arrays A=[1 2 3 4] and if K=3 then answer is 5 as we can see it clearly that sum array becomes like this : [3,4,5,5,6,7]

I can't go for all pair of i and j as N can go up to 100000. Please help how to solve this problem

I mean something like this :

```
int len=N*(N+1)/2;
int sum[len];
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
   for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
        sum[count]=A[i]+A[j]; 
        count++;
   }
}
//Then just find kth element.
```

We can't go with this approach

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436669/how-to-find-kth-largest-number-in-pairwise-sums-like-seta-setb?rq=1 ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Here we have just one array and also i CANT be equal to j

Comment: 100,000^2 = 10,000,000,000 - nothing a modern machine cannot process.

Comment: To get an answer you need to expand your example (maybe replace "and so on" with the actual values). To me it looks as though if N=4 then the length of the `sum` array would be 10. Am I correct? ... Also, you have this line in your code `sum=A[i]+A[j];` which is impossible, because `sum` is an array and cannot be assigned with a single integer value.

Comment: @amit I don't think it can be calculated within 1 sec ?

Comment: @user3840069 I see why not with the help of multithreading. Or is it a competition problem where performance is critical?

Comment: @amit No multithreading.

Comment: How large can each element of the given array be?

Comment: Is an `O(N * log(MAX_VALUE))` solution feasible?

Comment: @kraskevich Yeah it is. Each element can be upto 1000000. Also K is at max 50

Comment: @user3840069 I think adding this information to your question is a good idea.

Comment: The length calculation of the sum array should actually be this: `len=N*(N-1)/2`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you got this question from http://www.careercup.com/question?id=7457663.

If `k` is close to `0` then the accepted answer to [How to find kth largest number in pairwise sums like setA + setB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436669/how-to-find-kth-largest-number-in-pairwise-sums-like-seta-setb?rq=1) can be adapted quite easily to this problem and be quite efficient.  You need `O(n log(n))` to sort the array, `O(n)` to set up a priority queue, and then `O(k log(k))` to iterate through the elements.  The reversed solution is also efficient if `k` is near `n*n - n`.

If `k` is close to `n*n/2` then that won't be very good.  But you can adapt the pivot approach of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect to this problem.  First in time `O(n log(n))` you can sort the array.  In time `O(n)` you can set up a data structure representing the various contiguous ranges of columns.  Then you'll need to select pivots `O(log(n))` times.  (Remember, `log(n*n) = O(log(n))`.)  For each pivot, you can do a binary search of each column to figure out where it split it in time `O(log(n))` per column, and total cost of `O(n log(n))` for all columns.

The resulting algorithm will be `O(n log(n) log(n))`.

*Update:* I do not have time to do the finger exercise of supplying code.  But I can outline some of the classes you might have in an implementation.

The implementation will be a bit verbose, but that is sometimes the cost of a good general-purpose algorithm.

`ArrayRangeWithAddend`.  This represents a range of an array, summed with one value.with has an `array` (reference or pointer so the underlying data can be shared between objects), a `start` and an `end` to the range, and a `shiftValue` for the value to add to every element in the range.

It should have a constructor.  A method to give the `size`.  A method to `partition(n)` it into a range less than `n`, the count equal to `n`, and a range greater than `n`.  And `value(i)` to give the `i`'th value.

`ArrayRangeCollection`. This is a collection of `ArrayRangeWithAddend` objects.  It should have methods to give its size, pick a `random` element, and a method to `partition(n)` it into an `ArrayRangeCollection` that is below `n`, count of those equal to `n`, and an `ArrayRangeCollection` that is larger than `n`.  In the `partition` method it will be good to not include `ArrayRangeWithAddend` objects that have size `0`.

Now your main program can sort the array, and create an `ArrayRangeCollection` covering all pairs of sums that you are interested in.  Then the `random` and `partition` method can be used to implement the standard quickselect algorithm that you will find in the link I provided.

Comment: I added an outline of how you would go about implementing it.  I do not have time or interest to actually implement it, but it should be a fairly straightforward exercise.  Be warned that you'll be implementing binary searches, and those are notoriously easy to have minor mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is based on a fact that `K <= 50`: Let's take the first `K + 1` elements  of the array in a sorted order. Now we can just try all their combinations. Proof of correctness: let's assume that a pair `(i, j)` is the answer, where `j > K + 1`. But there are `K` pairs with the same or smaller sum: `(1, 2), (1, 3), ..., (1, K + 1)`. Thus, it cannot be the `K`-th pair.

It is possible to achieve an `O(N + K ^ 2)` time complexity by choosing the `K + 1` smallest numbers using a [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm(it is possible to do even better, but it is not required). You can also just the array and get an `O(N * log N + K ^ 2 * log K)` complexity.

Comment: Take N=3 and K=2 and array be [1 2 3 ]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it (in pseudo-code). I have now confirmed that it works correctly.

```
//A is the original array, such as A=[1,2,3,4]
//k (an integer) is the element in the 'sum' array to find

N = A.length

//first we find i
i = -1
nl = N
k2 = k
while (k2 >= 0) {
    i++
    nl--
    k2 -= nl
}

//then we find j
j = k2 + nl + i + 1

//now compute the sum at index position k
kSum = A[i] + A[j]
```

EDIT:
I have now tested this works. I had to fix some parts... basically the `k` input argument should use 0-based indexing. (The OP seems to use 1-based indexing.)

EDIT 2:
I'll try to explain my theory then. I began with the concept that the `sum` array should be visualised as a 2D jagged array (diminishing in width as the height increases), with the coordinates (as mentioned in the OP) being `i` and `j`. So for an array such as [1,2,3,4,5] the `sum` array would be conceived as this:

```
3,4,5,6,
5,6,7,
7,8,
9.
```

The top row are all values where `i` would equal 0. The second row is where `i` equals 1. To find the value of 'j' we do the same but in the column direction.

... Sorry I cannot explain this any better!

Comment: Only code (or pseudo code) answers are usually bad in algorithm questions, please provide the idea in words and explanation why it works as well.

Comment: Well, I had a go at explaining it, but I'm a coder, not a mathematician.